# Tensorflow: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train the network in Tensorflow which classifies the network traffic into 2 classes based on 3 features.

this is my dataset :

```
[[[80, 0.0, 1],
  [80, 10.00087022781372, 1],
  [80, 20.00172996520996, 1],
  [80, 30.002599954605103, 1],
  [80, 40.003480195999146, 1],
  [80, 50.00434994697571, 1]],
 [[80, 0.0, 1],
  [80, 10.00091004371643, 1],
  [80, 20.00171995162964, 1],
  [80, 30.00259017944336, 1],
  [80, 40.00345993041992, 1],
  [80, 50.00433015823364, 1]],
 [[372, 0.0, 1],
  [372, 10.000890016555786, 1],
  [372, 24.0006902217865, 1],
  [372, 45.0004301071167, 1]],...]
```

this is my network:

```
# Parameters
units_in_cell = 128
n_epochs = 3
learning_rate =0.001

batch_size = 1

n_features = 3
n_output = 1

#placeholder

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None , None, n_features], name = 'inputs')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'labels')

#cells and initial state

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.OutputProjectionWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=units_in_cell, activation=tf.nn.relu), output_size=n_output)

outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

# An additional dense layer before the final predictions
y_pred = tf.layers.dense(inputs=outputs, units=1, activation=None)
# Predictions (one dimensional)
y_pred = tf.squeeze(y_pred)

#loss
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs-y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    output_pred = []
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        print("Epoch: ", epoch+1,end=' \n ')
        for step in range(steps_per_epoch):
            for (a, b) in zip(train_x, train_y):
                X_values = np.array(a).reshape(1, np.array(a).shape[0], np.array(a).shape[1])
                y_values = b
                sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: X_values, y: y_values})

            if step % 10 == 0:
                c = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: X_values, y: y_values})
                print("Step: ", step+1, "loss = ", c,)

    print ("Opimization Finished")
    training_loss = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: X_values, y: y_values})
    print ("Training loss= ", training_loss)
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./models/tensorflow1.ckpt")
```

after running the network I got this error:

```
Epoch:  1 


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-95172c547171> in <module>
     15             #y_values = next(iter_train_y)
     16 
---> 17                 sess.run(train, feed_dict={x: X_values, y: y_values})
     18 
     19             if step % 10 == 0:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1102             feed_handles[subfeed_t] = subfeed_val
   1103           else:
-> 1104             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
   1105 
   1106           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    499 
    500     """
--> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    502 
    503 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'set'
```

If I run the network with dummy data, which are similar to my dataset, it works fine.

Could someone tell me what can be the problem?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: how did you define dummy data? Is your actual data the same length for the lists within the list? From the error message, it looks like maybe that could be the problem?